# Display after deletion in linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Actually this was another problem but it changed so I decided to open a new question.

My code is

```
typedef struct inner_list 
{
 int count;
 char word[100];
 inner_list*next;
} inner_list;
typedef struct outer_list
{
 char word [100];
 inner_list * head;
 int count;
 outer_list * next; 
} outer_list;
void delnode(outer_list **head,char num[100])//thanks to both Nir Levy and Jeremy P.
{
    outer_list *temp, *m;
    m=temp=*head; /*FIX #1*/
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        if(strcmp(temp->word,num)==0) {
            if(temp==*head) {
                delinner(temp->head); /* FIX#2 */
    *head=temp->next;

                free(temp);
                return;
            } else {
                delinner(temp->head); /* FIX#2 */ 
    m->next=temp->next;

                free(temp);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            m=temp;
            temp= temp->next;
        }
    }
    printf(" ELEMENT %s NOT FOUND ", num);
}
void delinner(inner_list *head) { /* FIX#2 */
    inner_list *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp=head;
    }
}
void delnode2(outer_list *up,inner_list **head,char num[100])
{
    inner_list *temp2,*temp, *m;
 outer_list *p;
 p = up;

 while(p!=NULL){m=temp=temp2=p->head; 
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        if(strcmp(temp->word,num)==0) {
            if(temp==(*head)) {
                *head=temp->next;

                free(temp);
                return;
            } else {
                m->next=temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            m=temp;
            temp= temp->next;
        }
    }
 p=p->next;
 }
    printf(" ELEMENT %s NOT FOUND ", num);
}
void print_node(outer_list *parent_node) 
{ 


 while(parent_node!=NULL){
 printf("%s\t%d\t", parent_node->word, parent_node->count);

    inner_list *child_node = parent_node->head;
 printf("list: ");
 if(child_node ==NULL){printf("BUARADA");}

 while (child_node != NULL) {
  printf("%s-%d", child_node->word,child_node->count);

        child_node = child_node->next;

        if (child_node != NULL) {
            printf("->");
        }
 }
    printf("\n");
 parent_node = parent_node->next;
 }
}
```

While deleting an element from outer list I am also trying the delete the same element from inner_list too.

For example: - Let's say aaa is an element of outer_list linked list and let's point it with outer_list *p - This aaa can also be in an inner_list linked list too. (it can be in p->head or another innerlist.) Now, the tricky part again. I tried to apply the same rules with outer_list deletion but whenever i delete the head element of inner_list it gives an error. Where is the wrong thing in print_node or delnode2?

Edit:
actually if it a outer_list node deleted the linked list of inner_list inside of it should be removed too. This is why delinner method used.

For example:

```
outer     inner
aaa       bb->cc
bb        aaa->cc

when i wanted to delete "aaa" The result should be:
outer     inner
bb         cc
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: well deletion is if the element to be deleted isn't the head of innerlist. when i wanted to delete the first element it gives an error while displaying. It can be a problem in delnode2 maybe it can't fully delete the node or print_node function has a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `inner_list **head` parameter of `delnode()` ? I assume that `up` is the outer list node, from whose inner list you want to remove the node containing the string given in `num`. `head` just doesn't fit into this picture. And you don't seem to be using it properly anyway. I rewrote the function a bit, omitting the parameter, changing the commented lines, and giving more meaningful names:

```
void del_inner_node(outer_list *up, char num[100])
{
  inner_list *temp, *m;
  outer_list *p;
  p = up;

  while (p != NULL) {
    m = temp = p->head;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
      if(strcmp(temp->word,num)==0) {
        if(temp==p->head) {   // refer to p->head
          p->head=temp->next; // refer to p->head
          free(temp);
          return;
        } else {
          m->next=temp->next;
          free(temp);
          return;
        }
      } else {
        m=temp;
        temp= temp->next;
      }
    }
    p=p->next;
  }
  printf(" ELEMENT %s NOT FOUND ", num);
}
```

Note that `temp2` is not used, so I removed it.

Now, in your code there is no call to `delnode2` (`del_inner_node`). You could actually call it within `delnode`, in case the searched string was not found in the current outer node:

```
void del_all_nodes(outer_list **head,char num[100])//thanks to both Nir Levy and Jeremy P.
{
    ...
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        if(strcmp(temp->word,num)==0) {
            ...
        } else {
            del_inner_node(temp,num);
            m=temp;
            temp= temp->next;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This way you can remove all nodes containing "aaa" with a single call:

```
outer_list *head;
// set up the lists
del_all_nodes(&head, "aaa");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me from a lot of codes but combining two things. Thanks.