# Remove duplicate elements from a sorted linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I am attempting a C program to remove duplicates from a Sorted linked list and i am using a simple concept of traversing the list from the start node. While traversing, compare each node with its next node. If data of next node is same as current node then i delete the next node.

My Code is:

```
struct node *remove_dup(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *p,*tmp;
    p=start;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        if(p->info==p->link->info)
        {
          tmp=p->link;  
          p->link=p->link->link;
          free(tmp);
        }
        p=p->link;
    }
    return start;
}
```

It is not giving me the correct answer! What is wrong with my execution? Is my concept wrong?

Comment: What's an example of input that doesn't produce the correct result?

Comment: The `p = p->link;` statement needs to go into the `else` branch.

Comment: Is there any error you're getting?

Comment: Yes, I realized the list is sorted, after posting it. Thus deleted my comment :)

Comment: Step through the code line by line, and after eah line, look at the linked list. At some point, the list will not be correct. That is the line with the mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a node from linked list in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848289/deleting-a-node-from-linked-list-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your code examines the next element, you need to stop when you are at the element one before last, like this:

```
while (p != NULL && p->link != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

The only reason to have the first part of the condition is to trap empty lists.

In addition, you should not advance the pointer when you remove an element. Otherwise, you would not process runs of more than two elements correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct node *remove_dup(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *p,*next;

    for(p=start; p; p = next) {
        next = p->link; 
        if( !next || p->info != next->info) continue;
        p->link = next->link;
        free(next);
        next = p;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Or the equivalent (without the messing with next)

```
struct node *remove_dup(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *p;

    for(p=start; p; ) {
        struct node *next = p->link; 
        if( !next || p->info != next->info) { p = next; continue; }
        p->link = next->link;
        free(next);
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: isn't it better to have `p =  p->link` in the for loop? (i meant inside ---- for (; ; p=p->link) )

Comment: No, because you don't want to advance after a delete.

Comment: but that is exactly what you are doing in the 1st line in the loop?

Comment: But the value of `next` is reset (conditionally) to p in the last line of the loop.

Comment: You can not just do that in your current implementation, I agree.

Comment: The new implementation is the same as the OP, except I added the test for p->link being NULL, and I swapped the condition to get rid of the bulky `if{}` block inside the loop. Plus I made the `p = p->link` conditional.

Answer (score 1):

```
void removeDuplicate()
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return;
    Node<T>* pPre = head;
    Node<T>* pCur = pPre->pNext;
    while (pCur != NULL)
    {
        if(pCur->elemet == pPre->elemet)
        {
            pPre->pNext = pCur->pNext;
            pCur = pPre->pNext;
        }
        else
        {
            pPre = pCur;
            pCur = pPre->pNext;
        }
    }

}
```

My answer in C++.

Answer (score 0):

My answer in Java:

```
public void removeDuplicate() {
    if (first == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("The linkedlist contains no nodes.");
    }
    Node temp = first;
    while (temp != null && temp.next != null) {
        if (temp.element == temp.next.element) {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same problem in java and came up with very small solution after struggling initially. Please take a look.

```
Node RemoveDuplicates(Node head) {
    Node curr = head;
    if(head==null)
        return head;
    while(curr.next!=null){
        if(curr.data == curr.next.data)
            curr.next = curr.next.next;
        else curr = curr.next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you need to check at the end as well that your current node is not the last node.
Here is the proper explanation and code given:
http://www.dscoding.com/2016/11/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-linked.html