# Deleting a node from the middle of a link list, function prototype is: int particle_remove(struct particle* p);

Tags: linked-list, particles

I have been working on this for like 10 hours.

```
int particle_remove(struct particle* p);
```

How do I find the head when I'm passing the location of the "node-to-be-deleted" to the function?

I know that:

```
prev->next = curr->next;
free(curr);
```

how do I find the location of the head to traverse down to (curr -1)?

This is what I have so far:

```
int particle_remove(struct particle *p){

    struct particle *curr = p;
    struct particle *prev = *head; /* should point to the head */

    if (p != NULL){
        while (prev != curr){
            prev=curr->next;
        }

        prev->next = curr->next;
        free(curr);                
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have been over this a million times and I can't think of how to get to the head node, without passing a parameter of the location of the head node into the function.  Is it possible to do this with the current function "signature" or do I have to add a reference to the head?

OK I have figured it out by creating a new function that takes both the current node to be destroyed and a pointer to the head, as I don't believe that just using a function to the node to be deleted will work as there is no reference to the head.  (Unless someone can prove me wrong, please do!)

I ended up with a prototype that looks like this: (for those that are looking for a hint)

```
 int particle_remove(struct particle *p, struct particle **head);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a node from linked list in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848289/deleting-a-node-from-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Considering you've been working on this for 10 hours already, do you have any additional code that you can share to help provide more context to your problem?  Or perhaps a more detailed description of what you've tried but can't get working yet?

Comment: Question updated with some code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: you have to change the head pointer if the pointer to be deleted (`p`) happens to be first in the list. Using a pointer-to-pointer (a pointer to the head pointer) is the easiest way:

```
int particle_remove(struct particle *p){

    struct particle **pp; /* should point to the head */

    for(pp = &head; *pp; pp = &(*pp)->next){
        if (*pp != p) continue;
        *pp = p->next;
        free(p);
        break;
        }    
    return 0;
}
```

If head is not a gobal pointer, you indeed end up with a function where the pointer to head is passed as an argument:

```
int particle_remove(struct particle **pphead, struct particle *p){

    for(   ; *pphead; pphead = &(*pphead)->next){
        if (*pphead != p) continue;
        *pphead = p->next;
        free(p);
        break;
        }    
    return 0;
}
```

BTW: the return value is nonsense. If there is no useful return for the function, it could just as well return void.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the way to solve this using the original function prototype is if you use:

```
if(p->next != NULL){
    /* do something */
}
```

You are checking to see if the next node is to be deleted.  This gives you access to the previous node and the next node (to be deleted).